# Keep displayed workspace after gnome-shell restart (Alt-F2+r)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell, pop-os

I'm currently following a tutorial in Youtube on how to develop a gnome extension. My IDE is currently in workspace 2 and every time I restart my gnome-shell via `Alt-F2+r` I will be back in workspace 1. I've googled a a few keywords but I cannot find a helpful answer on how to customize the gnome-shell behavior during restart to stay on the current workspace.
Some machine info that maybe helpful:
Pop! OS: 20.04
Gnome: 3.36.3
Windowing System: X11

Thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write your own quick script using two things - while I assume you will know about local user's PATH and such, I'll be detailed:

1. Replace the current Gnome shell; [see caveats](https://askubuntu.com/a/100228/431425)
2. Switch workspace to the desired number
3. Make script executable via GUI.

New file best goes to e.g. `/home/user/.local/bin` and you make sure your local path is loaded in `~/.profile` (note that `~/.bashrc` will not suffice as not necessarily loaded for GUI environments).

Script file - named e.g. `gnomerestart.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall -3 gnome-shell & wait
xdotool set_desktop 1
```

Note that `xdotool` will start counting desktops at 0. Check `xdotool get_num_desktops` and `xdotool get_desktop` for total number of workspaces and the ID of the current one, respectively.

Make executable:

```
 chmod +x ~/.local/bin/gnomerestart.sh
```

Now check if your local bin is enabled in `~/.profile` - add line if not already present.

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

To load the new profile you must make a new login once. If you want to override the "alt-F2+r" you might also just call it `r` and make sure to put the local path first in `~/.profile` - which you should always do if you want to override system-wide commands.

---

EDIT:

If you want to dynamically define the current workspace to be loaded, the script must be adapted using:

```
old_number=$(xdotool get_desktop)
killall -3 gnome-shell & wait
xdotool set_desktop ${old_number}
```